How to run Python script from Excel VBA in win11
I want to run a python script from Excel VBA and I get an error that says "Suspicious Macros Detected"
I already enabled macros and added it to trusted locations in Excel.
It has to do something with the Windows Defender and security changes because in win10 everything worked perfectly.
Any Idea what should I change in my settings to make it able to run?

Does this answer your question? Malicious Macro Detected when trying to run Python-Script from Excel-VBA
